# location of the message file in the ios system - [ ios 9.3.5 jailbreak cydia phoenix ]

Tags: ios, system, message, root, jailbreak

It is very important for me to download messages from the old iPhone 4s to my computer(windows) so I decided to jailbreake the system.
Using the ssh protocol, I connected on the computer with my phone and spent many hours searching for any files that could contain my messages. I realize that these files are very likely encrypted, but I would be extremely grateful for every circumstantial evidence.

I have five years of experience in programming and such matters, but for the first time I have the opportunity to look at the iOS system and I completely know where the apple could hide our messages. I would like to emphasize that the system only breaks in to be able to get my own messages to which I should have full right, but the apple does not facilitate such activities.
At the moment I am at the stage of searching for keywords using unix commands, including
**find -iname '* message *'**

It's best if someone familiar could show me the path to the file containing the messages.

PS: If I added a topic in the wrong section, I'm sorry, it's my first post here, I've been looking for solutions to some of my problems here.

**================================**
Ok, I think I found what I was looking for.
Thank you again **Creker** for help in finding the path to the SMS database. I still needed news from WhatsApp, but I found it myself.
For descendants: 
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/76E9A14F-02D4-4ABA-8972-80D5F48D5D7B/ChatStorage.sqlite


Topic to closing

Comment: You mean SMS messages? You can find them in `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/`. There's `sms.db*` SQLite database. For the record, iOS doesn't encrypt personal data at this level. Through SSH you can get basically anything you want apart from keychain. The latter is indeed encrypted, though you can still read it through keychain API.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot creker !

In addition to text messages, I also want to receive messages from the WhatsApp application (I know that it is possible to send messages via email, but my mailbox can not send a file that weighs 2 GB ...).
Also earlier, but also following the tracks and looking for an extension .db I was looking for a file including in
/Private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application
and
/Private/var/containers/
however, I can not find what I am looking for anywhere.

Maybe you know where to look?